# So i have a huge json file and i want to create a smaller version of it where one of the values is based on 2 of the values from the main file

Tags: javascript, json

I have a huge json file with array of objects. I want to go through that array and find a specific object then I want to return value based on 1 of its values.

Here is myfunction so far:

```
async function getMatchData(matchId,summoner){
    
    const response = await fetch(`https://europe.api.riotgames.com/lol/match/v5/matches/${matchId}?api_key=`+key);
    
    var data = await response.json();
    
    let matchData= {
        victory:
        players: data.info.participants.map(element => obj = { team: element.teamId, champ: element.championName, champIcon: element.championName + '_0.jpg', summoner: element.summonerName, level: element.champLevel, build: { item1: element.item1, item2: element.item2, item3: element.item3, item4: element.item4, item5: element.item5, item6: element.item6, item0: element.item0 }, kills: element.kills, deaths: element.deaths, assists: element.assists, kda: (element.kills + element.assists) / element.deaths, cs: element.totalMinionsKilled + element.neutralMinionsKilled, victory: element.win })
    }
  
   return matchData;
```

And here is what relevant part of  data would look like:

```
"metadata": {
        "dataVersion": "2",
        "matchId": "EUW1_6324729398",
    },
    "info": {
        "gameCreation": 1679399513246,
        "gameDuration": 106,
        "gameEndTimestamp": 1679399729794,
        "gameId": 6324729398,
        "gameMode": "CLASSIC",
        "participants": [{
                "puuid": "REWcFv1LhXs4Yfkoq9iD0ENCdZT-dCA__ThUz0wZZ6pDbpQE95SRJpPZVFQbZXYiS4OR6IMHdBpBsA",
                "summonerId": "QbkQflR7yU5XsQRuDS59HuTW9vP_heQYZBCleFV92OvEWiyWSwOoRuqX1w",
                "summonerLevel": 88,
                "summonerName": "Pridestalker",
                "win": true
            },...]
        }
```

I want `victory` to be = `data.info.participant.win` where `summonerName=summoner`.

Comment: Please be more descriptive of the problem. How is the existing function failing you? What isn't happening that should , what is happening that shouldn't?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
victory:  data.info.participants[data.info.participants.findIndex((element) => element.summonerName=summoner)].win
```

thats how i ended up doing it

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

```
victory: data.info.participants.find(e => e.summonerName == summoner).win;
```

Comment: heres the function im using it in`async function getProfileData(sumName){
    
    let summonerData = await getSummonerData(sumName);
    let puuid = summonerData.puuid;
    let matches = await getMatchIds(puuid);
   
    console.log(await getMatchData(matches[0]),sumName)

}` and here is the error
 victory:  data.info.participant.find(e => e.summonerName == summoner).win,
                                        ^

TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'find')

Comment: It should be `data.info.participants` with an s, I have updated my answer.

Comment: oh yes ofc but now theres another error
 victory:  data.info.participants.find(e => e.summonerName == summoner).win,
                                                                              ^
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'win')